# Is my pc temperature too high?

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature, gaming, burning

I have got an HP laptop which, at idle gets at 45 degrees. But when I start a game (like for example total war warhammer on low settings) the temperature goes to around 90-95 degrees. Is this too high or could this even damage my pc? because I sometimes can smell that something is burning. I measured the temperatures with Speccy and HWMonitor.

System:

- i5-4210M 2.60Ghz
- 12Gb RAM
- AMD Radeon HD 8500M/8700M
- Crimsom Relive 17.6.2

Comment: Are these temperatures GPU or CPU? Either way it is very dangerous for your PC to go above 85 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Do you use this laptop in a blanketed or otherwise area prone to heating?

Comment: the CPU was around the 95 degrees yes. And what do you exactly mean with your econd question?  @varfirstName

Comment: I saw this with another HP laptop I repaired. Turned out the heatsink compound was dried out and the heatsink was no longer making good contact. Once the heatsink compound was replace it had no issues. If you feel capable you should replace the heatsink compound. If not find yourself a local repair shop that can do it for you.

Comment: Do you sit like, in your bed with the laptops above blankets? Or on a coffee table with a cloth tablecover? The idea is that laptops heat up from insufficient ventilation sometimes. We just want to see if this is your problem before we tell you to do something else.

Comment: In the past I did this yes which damaged the ventilation( I think because it went downhill from then) but now I use a glass plate to put my pc on @varfirstName

Comment: Good to know that it can also be the heatsink @ianc1215

Comment: I would recommend getting a cooler like this: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834992853, reapplying your thermal compound, making sure your graphics card is working, and then seeing if it still hits 85+ degrees

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will surely try to get my hands on a cooler because that mostly worked for me, I cooled my pc off with an hairdyer( yes it really sounds stupid haha) which worked. I will also add the thermal compound and look if the graphics card works. @varfirstName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to get a laptop cooler. They can be less than $20 if you're budgeted, like [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834992853.).
- Buy some thermal compound to reattach your heat sink. Wipe the old stuff off with some 99% isopropyl alcohol and a rag.
- Run dxdiag.exe. It's already on your computer just type dxdiag in Run.. and it will pop up. Check your display driver, and make sure it's your graphics card.

Note: If you are going to be running intensive games, I would recommend investing in a gaming rig with a good GPU. Your poor laptop has probably been through so much that it's time to get a rig. Do your research before purchasing, though.

Comment: No problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

95°C - Yes, that's very high. I'm assuming the temperature you mention is when your cooling system is working fine. Although Intel processors are known to not burnout when they reach high temperatures(mostly they just switch off), but its better that you : -

- do not keep the laptop on a bed/thick fabrics
- Get a better cooling system.
- if your only purpose is to play performance hungry video games, better buy a dedicated GPU.

As for the normal temperature being 45°C, its not very high, but I would say, if you are running nothing extra than is required to keep the system running, it too is on the higher side.

Edit : As you pointed out that you already have an AMD GPU, make sure you have the correct drivers installed. Because the CPU temperature suggests that your GPU is not doing any computation for your game.

Comment: He has a laptop, Not a PC

Comment: This is a laptop.

Comment: Also they don't just switch off, it's called thermal throttling.

Comment: Hello, in the past I sometimes used my laptop on my bed (so the ventilation got coverezet which damaged it pretty much), but can this do that to my laptop? I looked inside my laptop and I found that the termal paste was nearly gone and yes I was thinking about buying a desktop pc with better specifications, but is it needed right here? @1c3b3r6

Comment: and sorry for the confusion, it is a laptop yes

Comment: Get a laptop cooler, doesn't absolutely need to have fans but it could help. In a pinch just a piece of wood or something to get the laptop off of the blankets can help a lot.

Comment: @BrianM if the thermal paste is gone, you need to get new thermal paste and apply it. This is a big problem. I would recommend getting a gaming rig for this purpose, but know how to put it together, and learn more about computers before you buy. Also I would recommend you get a cooler for your computer like this one: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834992853

Comment: @BrianM hey, no it was just a confusion, the question says "PC" so I thought you had a PC, but peers pointed it out that you have a laptop.